# React Navigation - create confirmation screen before exiting app

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am using `react-native` and `react-navigation` (v5), on Android, the back button will pop every screen up until there is no more screen and just exit the app.

I'd like to prevent the exiting and prompt the user with yes|no before exiting the app but examining the `navigation.state` or `canGoBack` didn't point to any clue about the final screen before exit

```
BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
    const canGoBack = navigation.canGoBack(); // always false
    const isFocused = navigation.isFocused(); // always true

    // TODO: how to check if we're on last screen?
    // I need to pop until last screen and display confirmation alert
    // navigation.state is a whole bunch of whores with no reliable way to check for last screen (I tried the _index_ and _history_

    if ( canGoBack && isFocused ) {
        navigation.goBack(); // never goes here
        return true; // means handled, default behaviour of popping screen won't be executed
    }
    return false; // not handled, react-navigation will pop screens and when no more screens to pop, will exit app
    // return true; // if I return true, no screens will get popped, and no auto-exit app also, but I need the pop until last
}
```

Does anybody know why `navigation.canGoBack()` always returns false, and if there is actually a way to check how many screens left to back?

Comment: In your code you're saying `canGoBack` always returns `false` and in your question you're saying it always returns `true`. Which one do you mean? It should only return `false` on the first screen, otherwise `true`.

Comment: it always returns false regardless of the screen, sorry for the typo..

Answer (score 1):

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
        Alert.alert('Are you sure', 'Do you really want to exit?', [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => null,
            style: 'cancel',
          },
          {text: 'YES', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
        ]);
        return true;
      };

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    }, []),
  );
```

This piece of code did work for me